# Complicated data formation

Tags: r

So I am trying to make a separate dataset that combines the yearly absence percentage and additionally binary variable of those with 10% or more total absence a year.

The absencePercentage should be calculated bycalculating total unauthorised and authorised absence divided by total possible sessions in all three terms.

Another thing is VioFlag. If the person has been flagged for Vio in at least one of the term, they should be flagged as VioFlagEver.

So the original data is like this:

```r
ID       PossibleSessions   Term     year     unauthorisedAbsence    authorisedAbsence    VioFlag
0110     46                 Sum      2014     0                     1                     0               
0110     116                Win      2014     1                     8                     1
0110     56                 Spr      2014     0                     5                     0
0110     44                 Sum      2015     21                    9                     0
0110     120                Win      2015     2                     2                     0
0110     58                 Spr      2015     10                    1                     0
```

So for ID 0110, he was absent for 15 sessions (0+1+1+8+0+5=15) out of possible 218 sessions (46+116+56=218). This means the absence percentage in 2014 for ID 0110 is 6.88%. He will not be the frequent absentee that year. But because in 2015, his absent rate was 20.27%, he will be a frequent absentee.

For ID 0110, He will be VioFlagEver for 2014 for not for 2015.

The new dataset I want to create is this.

```r
ID       year     absencePercentage    FrenquentAbsentee     VioFlagEver
0110     2014     6.88                 0                     1
0110     2015     20.27                1                     0
```

Please note that there are many IDs and year 2014 to 2018.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% group_by(ID, year) %>%
  summarize(absensepercentage = ((sum(unauthorisedAbsence) + sum(authorisedAbsence)) / sum(PossibleSessions))*100,
            violflagever = if_else(sum(VioFlag) > 0, 1, 0),
            frequentabsentee = if_else(absensepercentage > 10, 1, 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tidyverse (dplyr)` `group_by` and `summarize` to achieve this

```r
library(tidyverse)

read.table(textConnection("ID       PossibleSessions   Term     year     unauthorisedAbsence    authorisedAbsence    VioFlag
0110     46                 Sum      2014     0                     1                     0               
0110     116                Win      2014     1                     8                     1
0110     56                 Spr      2014     0                     5                     0
0110     44                 Sum      2015     21                    9                     0
0110     120                Win      2015     2                     2                     0
0110     58                 Spr      2015     10                    1                     0"), 
header = T) %>% 
  as_tibble() -> df


df %>% 
  mutate(totalAbscence = unauthorisedAbsence+authorisedAbsence) %>% 
  group_by(ID, year) %>% 
  summarise(possibleAbscence = PossibleSessions %>% sum(),
            totalAbscence = totalAbscence %>% sum(),
            VioFlagEver = VioFlag %>% sum()) %>% 
  mutate(absencePercentage = (totalAbscence/possibleAbscence)*100,
         FrenquentAbsentee = if_else(absencePercentage > 10, 1,0),
         VioFlagEver = if_else(VioFlagEver > 0, 1, 0))
#> `summarise()` regrouping output by 'ID' (override with `.groups` argument)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 7
#> # Groups:   ID [1]
#>      ID  year possibleAbscence totalAbscence VioFlagEver absencePercenta…
#>   <int> <int>            <int>         <int>       <dbl>            <dbl>
#> 1   110  2014              218            15           1             6.88
#> 2   110  2015              222            45           0            20.3 
#> # … with 1 more variable: FrenquentAbsentee <dbl>
```

<sup>Created on 2021-01-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>